# How to make flash work with PhantomJS?

Tags: flash, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 1.4.1 (support for plugins like Flash was removed in 1.5) complied with `--qt-4.8`.

I cannot get Flash to be enabled inside PhantomJS. I use the `--load-plugins=yes` option. I set up `QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH` to all the paths that contain libflashplayer.so:

```
QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/browser-plugins:/usr/lib/flash-plugin:/usr/lib/mozilla/plugin:/usr/lib64/flash-plugin:/usr/lib64/mozilla/plugins:/usr/lib64/opera/plugins
```

I can see in `strace` that PhantomJS does find `libflashplayer.so`:

```
stat("/usr/lib64/opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18782520, ...}) = 0
lstat("/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18782520, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18782520, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib64/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=18782520, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/lib/flash-plugin/libflashplayer.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=17047372, ...}) = 0
[..]
```

On the same server, Flash works fine with Firefox 10.0

Any idea why Flash is not being used by PhantomJS?

Answer (score 2):

> This document may be helpful: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support.
>
> In all cases, search the wiki pages and/or mailing-list for PhantomJS position on Flash (and other plugins). In short: if it works then please use it, otherwise it is not supported.

[Source](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=349)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11179) of setting up working environment for `CentOS 5.7` with `phantomjs 1.4.1`